# CSS file works in Safari but not in Google Chrome or Firefox

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, safari

When I open my index.html file in Safari, it shows everything, styled with my CSS file. When I open my index.html with Google Chrome, it appears to only show the HTML. I do not use webkits, and I only pair my HTML to my CSS using this in my head tag in my index.html file:

CSS:

```
<link rel=stylesheet type="html/css" href="stylesheet.css">
```

Does anyone know how I can open this in Google Chrome so it uses my CSS file like Safari does?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could be cached content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First clear cache of browser and disable some html/css validation extension.It will be sure that it will work. and just follow the css attachment syntax below.`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">`

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
```

The `rel` tag should have some quotation marks and the type should be text/css for compatibility.

Comment: Can you share some more Code so that we can reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with updating CSS, try <kbd>ctrl + f5</kbd>.

It also forces to reload the cache.

And if this is the problem, you can try to clear the cache in the browser.